# Are there any issues with replacing every ':-moz-any()' pseudo-class with ':is()' in CSS code?

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a bunch of CSS selectors that contain the Mozilla vendor-prefixed pseudo-class `:-moz-any`.

The target audience uses the latest version of Firefox.

Since `:is` is now fully supported in Firefox, I'm thinking it's best to replace all occurrences of `:-moz-any` with `:is` in the CSS code.

Are there any issues with doing this (such as what gets selected being changed, or any changes in specificity)?

Answer (score 0):

No*, there should be no issues with replacing it. In fact, you may want to revisit each selector and improve it:

From [*:-moz-any() selector grouping*](https://dbaron.org/log/20100424-any), David Baron's 2010 blog post explaining the new feature in Firefox:

> `:-moz-any()` is allowed to contain selectors with multiple simple selectors (using the css3-selectors definition of simple selectors, not the CSS 2.1 definition), ***but it is not allowed to contain combinators or pseudo-elements***. So you can write `:-moz-any(p.warning.new, p.error, div#topnotice)` or `:-moz-any(:link, :visited).external:-moz-any(:active, :focus)`, ***but you can't put "`div p`" or "`div > p` or "`:first-letter`" inside `:-moz-any()`***.

(Bold & italics emphasis mine)

You can see here that **neither pseudo-elements *nor* combinators worked with `:-moz-any()`**.

However, the [W3C Selectors Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#matches) spec's entry on `is()` says the following:

> The matches-any pseudo-class, ***`:is()`***, is a functional pseudo-class taking a [selector list](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#selector-list) as its argument. It represents an element that is represented by its argument.

If you click through the *selector list* link, you'll see it links to an explanation of a "list of simple/compound/complex selectors":

> A list of simple/compound/complex selectors is a comma-separated list of simple, compound, or complex selectors. This is also called just a selector list when the type is either unimportant or specified in the surrounding prose; if the type is important and unspecified, it defaults to meaning a [list of complex selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#list-of-simple-selectors).

Since the `is()` section didn't specify a *type* of selector list, we then assume it is the *complex selector list* as the quoted paragraph above explains. That list includes the following, specifically:

> A complex selector is a sequence of one or more compound selectors ***separated by combinators***.

(Bold & italics emphasis mine)

So, as you can see, we should be able to use combinators now with `is()`. Further, the only caveat it gives is on pseudo-elements; it doesn't say anything about not being able to use combinators:

> Pseudo-elements cannot be represented by the matches-any pseudo-class; they are not valid within `:is()`.

If we test this, we can see that Firefox *does* currently support combinators both inside `:is()` and outside of it in a single selector:

```css
:is(div, div > p) > span { 
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1>is():</h1>

<div>
  <span>This should be green.</span>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
    <span>This should be green too.</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
    <main>
        <p>
            <span>This should not be green.</span>
        </p>
    </main>
</div>

<p>
  <span>This should not be green either.</span>
</p>
```

So if you have any selectors that *could have* benefited, verbosity-wise, from being able to use combinators, you can now employ that feature.

* - Keep in mind this feature is currently [only supported in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=is()). Also, CSS Selectors Level 4 is currently only at the Working Draft stage. You should wait until it is at least a [Candidate Recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium#Candidate_recommendation_(CR)) or higher status before implementing it in production code, because the contents in a Working Draft are subject to change with little notice (as you can see from the fact that `is()` used to be called `matches()`.